# Why does w3wp memory keeps increasing?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, w3wp

I am on a medium instance which has 3GB of RAM. When I start my webapp the w3wp process starts with say 80MB. I notice that the more time passes this goes up and up.... Now I took a memory dump of the process when it was 570MB and the site was running for 5 days, to see whether there were any .NET objects which were consuming a lot but found out that the largest object was 18MB which were a set of string objects.

I am not using any cache objects since I'm using redis for my session storage, and in actual fact the dump showed that there was nothing in the cache.

Now my question is the following... I am thinking that since I have 3GB of memory IIS will retain some pages in memory (cached) so the website is faster whenever there are requests and that is the reason why the memory keeps increasing. What I'm concerned is that I am having some memory leak in some way, even if I am disposing all EntityFramework objects when being used, or any other appropriate streams which need to be disposed. When some specific threshold is reached I am assuming that old cached data which was in memory gets removed and new pages are included. Am I right in saying this?

I want to point out that in the past I had been on a small instance and the % never went more than 70% and now I am on medium instance and the memory is already 60%.... very very strange with the same code.

I can send memory dump if anyone would like to help me out.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your framework, but in general frameworks will do some caching as you have described. Essentially I wouldn't think you should be concerned unless you reach 3GB and your framework has not done some sort of garbage collection. You can test this by only giving it 200ish MBs and see if it garbage collects when it approaches the max. However, this is all conjecture maybe someone with more knowledge can give you a platform specific answer.

Comment: Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: David my website is showshappening

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue that is affecting a small number of Web Apps, and that we're working on patching.

There is a workaround if you are hitting this particular issue:

- Go to Kudu Console for your app (e.g. https://{yourapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole)
- Go into the LogFiles folder. If you are running into this issue, you will have a very large `eventlog.xml` file
- Make that file readonly, by running `attrib +r eventlog.xml`
- Optionally, restart your Web App so you have a clean w3wp
- Monitor whether the usage still goes up

The one downside is that you'll no longer get those events generated, but in most cases they are not needed (and this is temporary).

The problem has been identified, but we don't have an ETA for the deployment yet.

Comment: Hi the file in question was 1.8mb. However this started as from yesterday. Now something strange also happened yesterday. I modified my service plan to small and back again to medium so I reset all my processes and now the server is on the 40% memory mark which is quite fine even though the w3wp still increases slowly. Now at about 1.45AM when there were no users I saw my web server memory hit 97% of memory and basically there were no users on my website. Something strange really really happened. When I opened application insights I still found that the w3wp process did not increase.

Comment: @MarkFarrugia then you might be dealing with something different from what I described. Though to be sure, I'd still suggest trying to make it readonly and checking if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks David. Would you be able to check from server why there was that spike.... To be honest after I did that read only my IIS process is not increasing and the server's memory is stabilized at 40% unless something will now happen. Working set is now sitting at 250mb which is very good. Also on a mirror website I tested to recycle website at 03.00AM so that the process is always fresh and seems to be ok. I don't know whether this is good practice though.

Comment: David please can you help me... I again encountered this issue just like 1 hr ago. The w3wp process jumped to 2gb and the site terminated unexpectedly and was not loading anything. When I was checking errors it was telling me that a method where I am using redis was not being found which could not be the case since the code was not modified at all. If you go on webserver you would see that the memory jumped to 95% which is North europe.